# How to enable MP3, M4a support for Amarok?

Tags: mp3, kde, opensuse, amarok, m4a

How to enable MP3, M4A support for [Amarok](https://amarok.kde.org)? I am using the following:

- Amarok Version 2.0.1
- KDE 4.1.3
- openSUSE 11.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the [codec pack](http://opensuse-community.org/codecs-kde.ymp)?

According to [this site](http://linuxpoison.blogspot.com/2008/06/multimedia-support-in-opensuse-11-mp3.html) it should solve your problem.

Comment: zypper install yast2-metapackage-handler
Then simply click on the codecs-kde.ymp file

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but here it is September 2019 (Amarok v. 2.9.0) and just when I think I've got it all documented, it is **still** a struggle to get Amarok working with my m4a files on my new Fedora 30 build. This time, the main clue was here: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-mpeg-4-aac-decoder-for-centos-7-linux . What got it working for me was:

```
dnf install gstreamer{,1}-plugins-ugly gstreamer-plugins-bad-nonfree gstreamer1-plugins-bad-freeworld
```

Also, I had installed this previously. I'm not sure if they contributed to the success- it didn't work until the above dnf- but I installed it:

```
go to https://rpmfusion.org/Configuration, download the RPM Fusion Free and NonFree rpms. Install them using dnf.
dnf install python-devel ffmpeg-libs SDL2-devel SDL2_image-devel SDL2_mixer-devel SDL2_ttf-devel portmidi-devel libavdevice libavc1394-devel zlibrary-devel ccache
dnf install ffmpeg-libs, libavdevice
```

Afterwards, `dnf install amarok` and attempt to play an M4A file.

When I run Amarok from the command line, I see warnings e.g.,

```
amarok(5097)/phonon (KDE plugin): Can not create backend object from factory for  "GStreamer" ,  "phonon_gstreamer" :
```

That seems to be a red herring.

BTW, Amarok seemed to be able to play MP3 files out of the box. However, I had installed `ffmpeg-libs`, `libavdevice`, and `libavc1394-devel` prior to Amarok. So I don't know if they or one of their dependencies was what did the trick.

Comment: Good work persisting with this!